# Determine how many loops triggered for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a little complex stored procedure on SQL Server 2008 R2 and this SP also contains some user defined functions. Those UDFs and the SP itself has some while loops inside them.

I would like determine how many times something has been looped when I call this SP.

Any change I can do this?

Comment: Surely just by putting a variable with function-wide scope within the loop part and incrementing it by one each time. Then read the value at the end of the proc?

Comment: @Widor I am mostly looking for a auto solution. I was hoping maybe SQL Profiler has something to enable this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Profiler doesn't have any way to do this, as far as I know.  What I'd do is create a temporary table (provided you are only interested in the number of iterations for a single connection) to increment the single count variable, and then you can output the value that is stored in that temp table at the end of the loop.

Something like:

```
create table #countTable
(
    id int not null,
    countvar int not null
)
go

insert into #countTable
select 1, 0
go

-- your stored proc call here
--   during your iterations at the end, call this:
update #countTable
set countvar = countvar + 1
where id = 1
go

-- ...your stored proc ends now you want the count
select countvar
from #countTable
where id = 1
go
```

I made an `id` field in case there is more than one "counter" you may want.